# экранирование кавычек в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброго времени суток!

Необходимо чтобы следующая строка:

```py
pk_list_timestamp = 'date_trunc(''seconds'',' + ' '.join(row['"targetFieldName"'].lower().split()) +')'
```

Выводила значения вида:

```py
date_trunc('seconds',validdateto)
```

На данный момент вывод следующий:

```py
date_trunc(seconds,validdateto)
```

Comment: Экранировать отдельные символы можно с помощью обратного слэша

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов, первые два наиболее предпочтительны:

1. Использовать двойные кавычки
   `pk_list_timestamp = "date_trunc('seconds'," + ' '.join(row['"targetFieldName"'].lower().split()) +')'`
   *Пояснение: Если строка открывается двойной кавычкой, то и закрывается она только двойной кавычкой*
2. Экранировать кавычки внутри строки
   `pk_list_timestamp = 'date_trunc(\'seconds\',' + ' '.join(row['"targetFieldName"'].lower().split()) +')'`
   *Пояснение: добавление символа `\` перед кавычкой говорит компилятору о том, что это просто символ, а не конец строки*
3. Использовать big string
   `pk_list_timestamp = '''date_trunc('seconds',''' + ' '.join(row['"targetFieldName"'].lower().split()) +')'`
   *Пояснение: строки, которые открываются тройными кавычками (`'''текст'''` или `"""текст""")` игнорируют любые одинарные или двойные кавычки*

Если интересует почему у вас результат выходит именно такой:
Две строки, которые находятся друг за другом (`'Текст1' 'Текст2'`) будут автоматически склеены интерпретатором в одну строку (`'Текст1Текст2'`). В вашем случае `'date_trunc(''seconds'','` преобразовывается в `'date_trunc(' + 'seconds' + ','`, т.е. склеиваются.

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень помогло

Answer (score 0):

Используйте двойные кавычки для строк, тогда в них можно включать одинарные без экранирования:

```
pk_list_timestamp = "date_trunc('seconds'," + ''.join(row['"targetFieldName"'].lower().split()) +')'
```